# An activity Restored

Tags: android

I've searched hard for this, but can't figure out how to 'word' the question.

To put it simply:
If I hit the back button, my activity disappears. So far that's normal for an app.
But, when I restore it back from the phones standard 'overview' button (the square button on phones that show the Apps 'tiled' in the background), I want my App to toast a message: 'Welcome Back!'.
I know how to write the code to Toast my messages, that's no problem.

My question is this: How do I code a 'Listener' that will execute my Toast when the User restores the program from the 'overview' button?
Thanks :)

Comment: if the user pauses the app (by pressing home button) and then opens the app from the overview, do you still want to show Welcome back?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figure it out. Maybe this will help someone else down the line.

I used:

@Override
    public void onResume(){

```
    super.onResume();

    // Then toasted my message from here.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome Back!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Wasn't aware of the onResume() method.

Thanks anyway folks. :)

Comment: I came lately :), if you want to show different info when return activity, reference my answer,hope helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean isBack;
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isBack = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (isBack) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is going to always return false, you need to use on saved instance state and onrestore instance state to save the variable